# Why would my PHP mysql call not work? Nothing displays when executed

Tags: php, mysql

Why would my PHP mysql call not work? Nothing displays when executed

Simplified:

```
$votesSql = "SELECT SUM(col1) FROM database.table WHERE col2 = value";
$votes = mysqli_query($con, $votesSql);

<div class="col-md-1"><b id="<?=$data['discord_id']?>_vote_count"><?= $votes ?></b> Votes</div>
```

Comment: `mysqli_query()` returns a boolean. You need to fetch the results as well. I'll really advice that you get nice tutorials instead of copying and answer

Comment: Note: The object-oriented interface to `mysqli` is significantly less verbose, making code easier to read and audit, and is not easily confused with the obsolete `mysql_query` interface. Before you get too invested in the procedural style it’s worth switching over. Example: `$db = new mysqli(…)` and `$db->prepare("…")` The procedural interface is an artifact from the PHP 4 era when `mysqli` API was introduced and should not be used in new code.

Comment: Note: Try and get out of the habit of declaring SQL statements in throw-away variables that are used only once. It's a lot easier to follow code where the query is supplied directly to the function, and there's no longer a chance of messing up and sending in `$sql3` instead of the visually similar `$sql8`.

Comment: This is a `SELECT`, so it returns a mysqli_result object.

Answer (score 1):

You are missing the line where you `fetch the results` from the `query`, like this:

```
<?php
  $votesSql = "SELECT SUM(col1), discord_id FROM database.table WHERE col2 = value";
  $votes = mysqli_query($con, $votesSql);

  $row = mysqli_fetch_array($votes);    // you were missing this line

  echo '<div class="col-md-1"><b id="'.$row['discord_id'].'_vote_count">'.$row[0].'</b> Votes</div>';
?>
```

Though as @tadman already pointed out above, you should consider switching to `prepared statements` with `mysqli`.

Your query would then look something like this:

```
$con = new mysqli($servername, $username, $password, $dbname);

$votesSql = $con->prepare("SELECT SUM(col1), discord_id FROM database.table WHERE col2 = ?");
$votesSql->bind_param("s", $value);

$value = "yeah";
$votesSql->execute();

while ($row = $votesSql->fetch_array())
{
   echo '<div class="col-md-1"><b id="'.$row['discord_id'].'_vote_count">'.$row[0].'</b> Votes</div>';
}
```

more on `prepared statements` here: [php.net/prepared-statements](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.quickstart.prepared-statements.php).

Comment: I'm still getting the same empty result for some reason.

Comment: what are your table columns? Also no reason to use `database.table`, just put the `table name` like this `SELECT SUM(col1), discord_id FROM tableName WHERE col2 = 'value'`. If the col2 is a `varchar` type column then don't forget to add  the single parentheses `'` like this `col2 = 'value' "`.

Answer (score 0):

```
<?php
$votesSql = "SELECT SUM(col1) FROM database.table WHERE col2 = value";
$votes = mysqli_query($con, $votesSql);

while($data= $votes->fetch_assoc()) { // any fetch method use ?> 

<div class="col-md-1"><b id="<?=$data['discord_id']?>_vote_count"><?= $votes ?></b> Votes</div>

<?php } ?>
```